# How can I redirect users to edit post blog pages in Flask? syntax error

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

According video (7:32 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4Nz0cYuCnc&list=PLCC34OHNcOtolz2Vd9ZSeSXWc8Bq23yEz&index=20)
code 4 error

- Unindent does not match any outer indentation level
- Unexpected indent
- 'return' outside of function
- Statement expected, found Py:DEDENT

```
@app.route('/posts/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_post(id):
    post = Posts.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = PostForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.title = form.title.data
        post.author = form.author.data
        post.slug = form.slug.data
        post.content = form.content.data
        # Update Database
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Post Has Been Updated!")
        return redirect(url_for('post', id=post.id))
    form.title.data = post.title
    form.author.data = post.author
    form.slug.data = post.slug
    form.content.data = post.content
    return render_template('edit_post.html', form=form)
```

The code corresponds to the video.